# IIS And Multiple Projects with the same Project URL?

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7.5

If I open up IIS and expand Sites -> Default Web Site, I have 3 items which I've converted to applications:

`MyApp_Branch_01`

`MyApp_Branch_02`

`MyApp_Branch_03`

All 3 of these applications use the same AppPool. Their physical path corresponds to 3 unique directories on my physical drive; `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp_Branch_01`, `...02`, `...03`.

As you can probably guess, each directory contains a separate branch of our application in SVN. `01` is for doing builds, `02` is bug fixes & works-in-progress, `03` is for more "experimental" long-term projects. Each of these branches use different database connections. However, for all 3 of these, if I right click the build project and go to Properties, under the Web tab all 3 projects have the same value for the `Project URL` setting: they all point to `http://localhost/MyApp`.

I had just built the `MyApp_Branch_03` project and ran it. A coworker came over and asked some questions, so I had to open up `MyApp_Branch_01.sln`. I didn't build it, I didn't run it; I just opened it in Visual Studio. Meanwhile, I left `MyApp_Branch_03` debugging / running in my browser.

After helping my coworker, I returned to what I was doing... But now whenever I set a breakpoint in a controller, it would open up the file from `MyApp_Branch_01` instead of the `03` file in which I set the breakpoint.

I don't understand why / how this happens? How does IIS determine which set of DLLs to serve when you have multiple solution files which use the same url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about IIS determining which set of DLLs to serve. When you open a solution, Visual Studio automatically changes the physical path of WebSites if `IISUrl` element in your `csproj` file matches any WebSite in your Local IIS.

Comment: So basically VS just tells IIS to use [what VS thinks are] the right files?